# YII Css Bootstrap not loaded

Tags: yii

In localhost all seems working but during the export to the website, seems that the BOOTSTRAP Css isn't loaded... http://cra.ivao.ch . This is the code that I inserted on main.php on layouts folder...

Yii 1.1: bootstrap

```
<?php
    echo Yii::app()->bootstrap->registerAllCss();
    echo Yii::app()->bootstrap->registerCoreScripts();
    ?>
```

In local all sems working but during the export something isn't called...

This is the main.php for the component loading

```
'components'=>array(
        'bootstrap'=>array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are using [Yiistrap](https://github.com/Crisu83/yiistrap) and if not comment and I will add whatever extension you are using.

Add this line on main.php

`<?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->register(); ?>`

Comment: I'm Using Yii 1.1: bootstrap .. Added also this line but nothin's changed

Comment: Is there any reason that you use that old (unsupported?) YB?

Comment: Do you use version from here: http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/
If yes no need for two lines. Where did you get your YB?

Comment: maybe need add 'preload' => array('bootstrap') in config file